# Reskit POST of array of nsnumbers makes string JSON fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, restkit, nsnumber

When I POST a mapped model through Restkit the resultant Json looks like so, the doubles are strings,  I want them to be doubles:

```
 {
    Coordinate =     (
        "39.2",
        "-121.0"
    );
 }
```

I want:

```
{
    Coordinate =     (
        39.2,
        -121.0
    );
 }
```

this is my mapping

```
+(RKObjectMapping *)mapping
{
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[self class]];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"Coordinate"]];

    return mapping;
}
```

When setting the coordinate of the Location object:

```
@interface MYLocationDTO : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *Coordinate;

+(RKObjectMapping *)mapping;


@end
```

I am passing in an array of two nsnumbers, that were set from double values.

Anyone know of how to post this nsarray collection as numbers not strings?
Thanks!

Here is my post call:

```
-(void)updateLocationOfUserWithLocationDTO:(WHMLocationDTO *)dto withCompletionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL, NSString *))callbackBlock

{
    //whim-ios.herokuapp.com/users/password-reset
    RKObjectManager *manager = [WHMDataController getManagerWithSession];


    RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [[WHMLocationDTO mapping] inverseMapping];

    RKRequestDescriptor *requestDesc = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[WHMLocationDTO class] rootKeyPath:nil method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

    [manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDesc];

    RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [WHMResponseMapping responseMapping];

    RKDynamicMapping *dynamicMapping = [WHMResponseMapping createDynamicMappingWithResponseMapping:responseMapping];

    [manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:dynamicMapping method:RKRequestMethodPOST pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]];



    //POST
    __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
    [manager postObject:dto
                   path:@"user/loc"
             parameters:nil
                success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result)
     {
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use Apple's API to generate the JSON, as demonstrated in this article: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5 
and just POST the JSON?

Comment: Probably because RESTKit does that for you.

Comment: yep.. Restkit is supposed to do the value transformation for you.

Comment: If it's only transforming it to strings, and you want floats, you might want to consider an alternative method.